# How to enable WCF net.tcp in IPSec?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2, net.tcp, ipsec

I'm trying to connect from a web app to another web app using the WCF.NET NET-TCP protocol. This net.tcp protocol is enabled in IIS and is using the port TCP 808 in my case.
I've configured IP Filter in the server, but it blocks the connection between both applications unless I completely disable IP Filter.

This is the rule I've tried to add, and which doesn't work:

```
Source address: Any IP Address
Destination address: My IP Address
Protocol: 6 (TCP)
From Port: Any port
To Port: 808
Action: Permit
```

Using TCPView, when the connection is blocked shows:

```
Protocol   Local Address       Remote Address    Status
TCP        server.com:64706    server.com:808    SYN_SENT
```

How do I permit this connections? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

If Any IP -> My IP is the ingoing rule, then I had to add the outgoing rule too; which would be My IP -> Any IP.

Details:

```
Source address: My IP Address
Destination address: Any IP Address
Protocol: 6 (TCP)
From Port: Any port
To Port: 808
Action: Permit
```

Hope this helps.